# Special use of args / kwargs

Tags: python, keyword-argument

I need to do something like this:

```
def func1(a, *args, b="BBB", **kwargs):
    print "a=%s b=%s args=%s kwargs=%s" % (a, b, args, kwargs)
```

So that calling like this:

```
func1("AAAA", h="HHH", j="JJJ")
```

Produces the output:

```
a=AAAA b=BBB args=() kwargs={'h': 'HHH', 'j': 'JJJ'}
```

But it is not possible to put a default named argument after `*args`. (`SyntaxError: invalid syntax`)

- Why is this not allowed?
- Is there any readable way to implement this? The only way I know is `b=kwargs.pop("b", "BBB")`, but this is not very readable. I would prefer to have this in the function call definition, where it belongs: it is a parameter which will *always* have a value, either a default value or a user-given value.

## EDIT

I could put `b` in front of `args`:

```
def func1(a, b="BBB", *args, **kwargs):
    print "a=%s b=%s args=%s kwargs=%s" % (a, b, args, kwargs)
```

But that would mean that this call:

```
func1("AAAA", "CCC", h="HHH", j="JJJ")
```

Assigns `"CCC"` to `b`, which I do not want. I want `b` to be a named arg, not a possitional arg.

Comment: Why not put b='BBB' before *args?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's perfectly valid in Python 3 ([demonstration](http://liveworkspace.org/code/gHHOt%244)); [PEP 3102](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) introduced **keyword-only arguments**.

In Python 2.x you'll have to continue using `kwargs.pop`, or an appropriate decorator:

- http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577940-emulate-keyword-only-arguments-in-python-2/
- https://pypi.python.org/pypi/kwonly

Answer (score 1):

[In Python 2](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/),

> The current Python function-calling paradigm allows arguments to be
>   specified either by position or by keyword.  An argument can be filled
>   in either explicitly by name, or implicitly by position.

As a consequence `def func1(a, *args, b="BBB", **kwargs)` would be ambiguous and is therefore not allowed: in a call `func1(1, 2)`, should `args == ()` and `b == 2`, or `args = (2,)` and `b == "BBB"`?

This is why `def func1(a, b="BBB", *args, **kwargs)` is, on the other hand, accepted (even though it does not do what you want): `b` is always passed as the second argument, even in a call like `func1(1, c=3, b=2)` (it is equivalent to `func1(1, 2, c=3)`).

As ecatmur noted, Python 3 changed the way arguments are handled, which brings the flexibility you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
def func1(a, *args, **kwargs):
    b, k = (lambda b="BBBB", **k: b, k)(**kwargs)
    print "a=%s b=%s args=%s kwargs=%s" % (a, b, args, k)
```

could be an alternative.