# Why do I have to use * in front of a list in str.format(*args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, string, format, variadic-functions

After reading these:
[Special use of args / kwargs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15545711/special-use-of-args-kwargs)
https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/
[What does ** (double star) and * (star) do for parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36901/what-does-double-star-and-star-do-for-python-parameters)
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#formatstrings

I want to be sure I understand well: `str.format(*args, **kwargs)`

if `uniques` is a list of two integers such as `[0, 0]`, which I would use for example in a loop with a condition to increment the first element and no condition to increment the second, with:

```
 print('Task finished. {0!s} retrieved out of {1!s} tested'.format(*uniques))
```

I do have to use `*uniques` because instead `uniques` would be passed as a tuple to format. But if I do use

```
 print('Task finished. {0.[0]} retrieved out of {0.[1]} tested'.format(uniques))
```

It raises value error: `ValueError: Empty attribute in format string`. Using brackets around `uniques` doesn't help. I don't really get why? Could someone please clarify?

In the first case, is the list unpacked then converted to a tuple, while in the second, it is not because the list can't be converted by format as a tuple right away, the same way `format(uniques[0], uniques[1])` would? If I am right, why is that the case, since there's is a `tuple(list)` function to do that and so, it is very simple?

Comment: Does '...'.format(*(uniques, )) work?

Comment: No it doesn't. Thanks for trying to help. I elaborated my post while you answer, with the edit at the end?

Comment: Ah sorry I did not read the question properly :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing *attribute* and *subscription* syntax. `0.[0]` tells the format to look for an *attribute* by the name `[0]`. However, the [formal grammar](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) only allows for a [valid *identifier*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-identifier) to follow the dot (meaning a word formed of letters, digits and underscores, starting with a letter or underscore), and `[0]` doesn't match that rule, so you get an error that there is no attribute name at all.

Drop the dots:

```
print('Task finished. {0[0]} retrieved out of {0[1]} tested'.format(uniques))
```

This now works, because now the format parser correctly sees subscriptions:

```
>>> uniques = [0, 0]
>>> print('Task finished. {0[0]} retrieved out of {0[1]} tested'.format(uniques))
Task finished. 0 retrieved out of 0 tested
>>> uniques = [42, 81]
>>> print('Task finished. {0[0]} retrieved out of {0[1]} tested'.format(uniques))
Task finished. 42 retrieved out of 81 tested
```

The `0[0]` specifier tells the `str.format` parser to use the first positional argument (here provided by `uniques`) and then threat that as a sequence by subscribing to `[0]`, so the first element.

When you use `'...'.format(*uniques)`, any *iterable* will do, be it a list or a tuple or a different kind of iterable (including generators); Python iterates over it to produce separate arguments. For `[42, 81]` that means Python will call the method as if you called it with `'...'.format(42, 81)` either way. In the string format, you then have to address these separate arguments with `{0}` and `{1}`.

Comment: I guess there's no answer here to how can I be so dumb, but you're awesome! I guess anyway, *list is more pythonic and formal, but I wanted to be sure to understand the mechanics even if I would not use it. Just for elation and peace of the mind.

Comment: @AndoJurai: it depends on what you want to do; if you have a variable number of templates, using named slots with attributes or subscriptions can a be very powerful way to make those templates more flexible, applying a whole namespace mapping to them with `template.format(**mapping)`.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in your format string:

```
print('Task finished. {0[0]} retrieved out of {0[1]} tested'.format(uniques))
```